# Trying to understand discontinuity by examples

Tags: calculus

Here are some examples :

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}$$

We say that the limit does not exist since right hand and left hand limits are not equal.

So, does the limit of 
$$g(x)=\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}$$ 
exist?

And, also consider 
$$h(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{\sec x}}$$ 
Does this limit exist and is it infinity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjoin $\infty$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and still have a metric space whose structure is compatible with the usual structure. Defining $g(1)=\infty$ turns $g$ into a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}\cup\left\{\infty\right\}$.

As for $h$, the limit does not exist.

Comment: I have no knowledge of metric spaces whatsoever. I just started doing analysis.

Comment: Then you should return to this question when you know about metric spaces or topology.  That's the proper setting for considering this question. Intuitively $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}g(1)=+\infty$ says that if we can define $g(1)=+\infty$ in a reasonable way, then $g$ is continuous in $1$. That's exactly what one can do.

Comment: Mathematician 42, there is no need for adjoining $\infty$, $f$ is continuous on its natural domain $\Bbb R\setminus\{1\}$.